# Calling Direct2d PngBitmapEncoder.Initialize fails when called from VB.net using SharpDX

Tags: vb.net, direct2d, sharpdx

I have the following code written in VB.NET 2010 running on Windows 8.1  :

```
>Dim pixelFormat As System.Guid = WicPixelFormat.Format32bppBGR
>Dim wicFactory As ImagingFactory = New ImagingFactory()
>Dim wicBitmap As Bitmap = New Bitmap(wicFactory, width, height, pixelFormat, BitmapCreateCacheOption.CacheOnLoad)

>' A bunch of rendering code goes here.  The renderTarget is closed with endDraw
>'There don't seem to be any errors in the rendering code.

>Dim stream As WICStream = New WICStream(wicFactory, "test9.png", SharpDX.IO.NativeFileAccess.Write)
>Dim encoder As SharpDX.WIC.PngBitmapEncoder = New  SharpDX.WIC.PngBitmapEncoder(CType(wicFactory, System.IntPtr))
>encoder.Initialize(stream)
```

The same code ported to C# runs fine but when run in VB the encoder.initialize statement fails with a protection exception.  Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?  I tried setting the stream to zero (with a seek) but it makes no difference.

Brian

Comment: Interesting update.  I created a C# function (as a class library) and moved the failing code to C# and called it from VB and it all worked so I worked backward moving code line by line back to VB to find which statement was the problem.  Turns out that the intellisense in VS 2010 was insisting that the call to create the PngBitmapEncoder wanted a system.Intptr in VB but an Imaging Factory in C#.  I took out the cast and it squawked with option strict on.  I moved it to VS 2013 Community edition and the intellisense now says it wants an Imaging Factory just like C#  and it works fine.

Comment: I had always assumed that the intellisense picked up its values from the meta data associated with the library.  Can anybody explain why VS 2010 has different intellisense than VS 2013 when pointed at the same SharpDX library?

Comment: Maybe VS 2010 was confused by the fact that one constructor is `PngBitmapEncoder(ImagingFactory factory)` and the other is `PngBitmapEncoder(ImagingFactory factory, Stream stream = null)`. The [documentation](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/t-sharpdx-wic-pngbitmapencoder) doesn't show the default argument, but the [source](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX.Direct2D1/WIC/PngBitmapEncoder.cs) does. In any case, you don't generally want to use the `IntPtr` constructors in SharpDX.